# Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's self (!)?

Tags: python

I'm having to move to Python to integrate code into some existing Python code. One of the things that either I've overlooked or just doesn't seem to exist is being able to perform replacements on the object itself.

For example, a common thing I would do is something like this:

```
textstring = "I am the walrus"
textstring.gsub!(/am/,"was")
```

which then makes textstring itself the object of the global replace as opposed to:

```
newtextstring = textstring.gsub(/am/,"was")


2.4.0 :005 > textstring = "I am the walrus"
 => "I am the walrus" 
2.4.0 :005 > newtextstring = textstring.gsub(/am/,"was")
 => "I was the walrus" 
2.4.0 :006 > puts textstring
I am the walrus
 => nil 
2.4.0 :007 > puts newtextstring
I was the walrus
```

what I haven't found a way to do this using the Python re module. But I'm sure I've just overlooked something.

Comment: how about `textstring = textstring.replace('am', 'was')`? Generally in Python, some operations happen in-place (no need to assign the result back to the variable) and some are not. `replace` is of the latter kind.

Comment: You didn't overlook anything,  Python strings are immutable. Also we don't regexps for things that can be done with a simpler method (in this case `"I am the walrus".replace("am", "was")`). Python might seems similar to Ruby at first but it's really a totally different language and philosophy.

Comment: Thanks Bruno... My example was over simplified. You're right, a regex isn't needed there. But in my real code, one is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible in Python because as opposed to Ruby, strings are immutable.

Generally speaking, if an object has methods that change its data then it is considered mutable. Many builtin objects are mutable and the mutation is invoked by a method call, this does not require a  special operator in Python.

Example 1: remove the last item from a list.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> mylist.pop()
3
>>> mylist
[1, 2]
```

Example 2: `sorted` returns a new list, `list.sort` sorts a list in-place.

```
>>> mylist = [5, 4]
>>> sorted(mylist)
[4, 5]
>>> mylist
[5, 4]
>>> mylist.sort()
>>> mylist
[4, 5]
```

You just have to know which functions/methods work in place or read the docs.

> is it always the case that methods of mutable objects operate in-place? Can't seem to think of a counter-example at the moment.

But there's plenty.

```
>>> mylist.__add__(mylist) # mylist + mylist
[4, 5, 4, 5]
>>> mylist
[4, 5]

# mylist[:] is mylist
>>> mylist.__getitem__(slice(None, None, None)) is mylist
False
```

Comment: is it always the case that methods of mutable objects operate in-place? Can't seem to think of a counter-example at the moment..

Comment: I used a super simple example, but I think the answer is the piece I was lacking. Thanks!